# Unable to Upgrade from CiviCRM 4.6.16 to 4.7 (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, 4.7

When attempting to upgrade from CiviCRM 4.6.16 to any of the 4.7 releases, I receive the following error message:

Error: Migrate "on behalf of" information to module_data

Debug info says: "Unknown column 'for_organization' in 'field_list'

This is the first time I've encountered any issues during the upgrade process. I have been using CiviCRM since version 4.4.

Screenshot is below. Thank you for your help!
Darron

[image: Error message screenshot]

Comment: I'm not seeing you received any help for this. I'm also struggling with the upgrade process. I did find some help elsewhere. Although it wasn't sufficient - perhaps it would help you. It is possible you might have Drupal DB updates to execute before hand. I'm not using drush - but I did find some updates were needed when I checked the status report. https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=37002.0

Answer (score 1):

Problem is old field was lost in the upgrade. Try updating this file:

CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FourSeven.php

with code at this [GIT pull request](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10620/files).

This post [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19376) explains it in more detail.

Comment: As a reminder, Stack Exchange frowns upon answers consisting of only a link; such answers may be deleted at any time. You should provide a summary or excerpt of the concept available at the link, particularly as external URLs are unstable and may become unavailable over time.